# Resize of ATL Activex control hosted in Internet Explorer

Tags: activex

We have an `ATL Activex control`, which is hosted in Internet Explorer. We wanted to re-size the `ATL activex control` along with the IE browser. Handled the `WM_SIZE` as below:

```
MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SIZE, OnSize)
```

which has written the `OnSize` handler for the respective class. But, the `WM_SIZE` even is not getting fired.

We have created the `ATL activex` in IE as below:

```
OBJECT classid="clsid:89431EB0-39AC-4544-A0AA-69247BA16B04" id="ISRControl" height="100%" width="100%"
```

Please, let me know if you have any suggetions. So, that it would be helpul for us.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Yes finally I got the solution.

actually In my ATL Activex control I have already handled the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED event. so WM_SIZE event is not post to control if it has the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED. WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED handler will get the new size co-ordinates.so I Called the MoveWindow of the control. so it automatically fires the WM_SIZE.